# Monitor file/folders to get change notifications in UNIX

Tags: java, unix, file-monitoring

The requirement is to monitor multiple folders and file for any changes in UNIX. I need to be able to hook my java code for any changes like  create/modify/delete. Could anybody suggest any java based frameworks to do the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use Java 7, you can use the [WatchService API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) to monitor changes to the file system.

If you are stuck with Java 6-, you can have a look at some alternatives proposed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10008351/file-system-change-monitoring-through-java) or [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096404/is-there-a-sophisticated-file-system-monitor-for-java-which-is-freeware-or-open).

Comment: We have a restriction to use only java 6. Could you please suggest any framework that is compatible with java 6, and open-source?

Comment: @Mithun I have added two links with java 6 compatible libraries.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at Java 7's [File Notifier service](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) ?

> The java.nio.file package provides a file change notification API,
>   called the Watch Service API. This API enables you to register a
>   directory (or directories) with the watch service. When registering,
>   you tell the service which types of events you are interested in: file
>   creation, file deletion, or file modification. When the service
>   detects an event of interest, it is forwarded to the registered
>   process. The registered process has a thread (or a pool of threads)
>   dedicated to watching for any events it has registered for. When an
>   event comes in, it is handled as needed.

[JNotify](http://jnotify.sourceforge.net/) is a similar service/library for those who can't use Java 7.

Answer (score 1):

Java 7 has introduced `WatchService` which watches registered objects for changes and event.

Example -

```
Path myDir = Paths.get("D:/test");       

    try {
       WatchService watcher = myDir.getFileSystem().newWatchService();
       myDir.register(watcher, StandardWatchEventKind.ENTRY_CREATE, 
       StandardWatchEventKind.ENTRY_DELETE, StandardWatchEventKind.ENTRY_MODIFY);

       WatchKey watckKey = watcher.take();

       List<WatchEvent<?>> events = watckKey.pollEvents();
       for (WatchEvent event : events) {
            if (event.kind() == StandardWatchEventKind.ENTRY_CREATE) {
                System.out.println("Created: " + event.context().toString());
            }
            if (event.kind() == StandardWatchEventKind.ENTRY_DELETE) {
                System.out.println("Delete: " + event.context().toString());
            }
            if (event.kind() == StandardWatchEventKind.ENTRY_MODIFY) {
                System.out.println("Modify: " + event.context().toString());
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e.toString());
    }
}
```